# Have I killed it

Tags: audio

I dropped my poor iPod again it is a generation 4 64gb, I use it for listening to audio books. I did buy it a protective hard hat because I have dropped it before, but this time the sound has gone very very soft.  I tried a new set of earphone without any joy, I an 70 years old so no complicated suggestions please.  I have been reading various things online but think I may have killed it this time has anyone out there got any hope for me.  Or Have I got to ask Santa for a new one?

Comment: Do you have a cell phone that can play podcasts?  Most modern phones during the last 5 years have the ability to play podcasts.  Will that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance you may have killed it, however..... You can try to take it to an apple store and see if anyone there can fix the issue.

Comment: Apple most likely won't fix an old iPod.